# Validation rule on Picklist and Multipicklist

Tags: formula, picklist, validation, validation-rule, multi-select

```
AND(
    INCLUDES(Site_Location__r.Tracks__c ,TEXT(Track_Assignment__c))
)
```

`Site_Location__r.Tracks__c` is Multipicklist, and `Track_Assignment__c` is picklist field.

I am trying to write a validation rule to check if the `Track_Assignment__c` value is contained in the `Site_Location__r.Tracks__c` Multipicklist".

**Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'INCLUDES()'. Expected Text Literal, received Text**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note from the documentation on [`INCLUDES`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=0&language=en_US#INCLUDES) that the syntax is:

```
INCLUDES(multiselect_picklist_field, text_literal)
```

A **text literal** is a single explicit value such as `"My Picklist Value"`. You can't compare another field here, because **text** is a different type that is not accepted in this case. You will need to write an `Apex Trigger` to perform this validation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have already written the trigger, however just wanted to check if we can avoid the trigger.